# ListBox inside another ListBox

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, data-binding

I have a simple class like this:

```cs
public class myClass
{
    public List<string> innerList;
    public string innerString{get;set;}
}
```

And then I have a List of objects of this class: List<myClass>. For example content of this list is

```cs
myList = new List<myClass>{
    new myClass{
        innerList = new List<string>{
            "1", "2", "3", "4"
        },
        innerString = "First String"
    },
    new myClass{
        innerList = new List<string>{
            "a", "b", "c", "d"
        },
        innerString = "Second String"
    }
};
```

I want to display this array context in the following form:

```
First String
  1  2  3

Second String
  a  b  c
```

Note: actually I cannot concatenate 1+2+3 and a+b+c because what I have is not string array but an BitmapImage array (thats why I think that I need another listbox for this)

So, I think I should make a listbox inside another listbox. But possibly there is better way to do this exists.

Here my not_working XAML code:

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ''}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding innerString}"/>
                <ListBox x:Name="innerListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding innerList}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBox Text="{Binding ''}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

It displays only "First String" and "Second String", but not "1 2 3" and "a b c".

What should I do to display an Array content inside another Array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you remove the list item template for the inner list, your xaml should work just fine.

If you do not supply an `ItemTemplate`, then the default ListItem is used, which simply calls the `ToString()` method of the `DataContext`, which in this case is a `string`

one other thing to note, is that if you want your list to dynamically update, you should be using `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>`.  `ObservableCollection` implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, wich tells the UI that an item is added or removed.

Comment: First of all, thank you for notify about `ObservableCollection`. Very useful tip. And I realize where was my error: I've forgot to set {get;set;} methods to my List inside myClass. Your comment about that this XAML should work made me think and doublecheck my cs code ) Thank you )